# Access 2010 How to : VBA to export

Tags: ms-access, export, vba

Another question regards auto export in Access.
I use the database to create timetables for a Virtual Airline.

To import these timetables into my website it has to be in the following format:

CODE,FLTNR,DEPARTURE,ARRIVAL etc.

Now i know how to export it in this way, but i want it to be automatic via a script or macro so i can use it inside a switchboard.

Now i have found a lot of information but nothing i understand clear.

Any help here would be appriciated.

Kindly regards,

Rick Winkelman

Answer (score 0):

What type of file do you need?  I put the following at the end of a VB script to create a .csv from a query/table:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, [source query], "target.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnTimer event to launch the VBA code that exports the data.  It's a form-based event, and you set it to launch at any interval you like.

You **could** set it to launch once every 24 hours, but that's not always safe.  Usually, I set it to launch every 15 or so minutes and check the system time when it does.  If the system time is >= 7:45PM and < 8PM, I tell it to run the VBA code.

Below is the OnTimer event I use, along with the 2 functions it calls.  Set the form's Timer Interval to 900000 (15 minutes) and leave the form open.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

Select Case True

    Case (Format(Now(), "short time") >= "04:45") And (Format(Now(), "short time") < "05:00")
        Forms!frmPrimary!dtMAINFRAME = "4:45"

        Call Cleanup

    Case (Format(Now(), "short time") >= "07:45") And (Format(Now(), "short time") < "08:00")
        Forms!frmPrimary!dtMAINFRAME = "7:45"

        Call chkforweekend

End Select
DoEvents

End Sub
```

chkforweekend function:

```
Public Function chkforweekend()

chkforweekend = True
day = Date

sDate = Weekday(day, vbSunday)

If sDate <> 1 Or sDate <> 7 Then
    chkforwekend = False
End If

End Function
```

Cleanup function:

```
Public Function Cleanup()

Forms!frmPrimary!lblStatus.Caption = "Cleaning up my mess..."
DoEvents

ReturnCode = utl_DisconnectSession
ReturnCode = utl_StopSession

fCloseApp ("com.ibm.eNetwork.HOD.SessionFrame")
Call Sleeper(3000)
fCloseApp ("com.ibm.eNetwork.HOD.SessionFrame")
Call Sleeper(3000)
fCloseApp ("javax.swing.JFrame")

Forms!frmPrimary!lblStatus.Caption = "status"
Forms!frmPrimary!lblStatus.Visible = False
DoEvents

NewEECountsRun = False
NewMraRptRun = False
NewBATT = False
NewC_STE_PRun = False
NewCEDMBRCNT9_PRun = False
NewWklyMbrRptRun = False
CaseListRun = False

End Function
```